# Serialise BigDecimal, BigNumber, BigInt etc. to and from JSON

Tags: javascript, types, json-deserialization

What types, and what serialisation pattern, can I use to ensure I have **arbitrary-precision numbers** in my JavaScript program while it's running, but the **state is serialised to / deserialised from JSON** with a minimum of pain?

I am writing an application that makes heavy use of numbers with higher precision than allowed by the ECMAScript native `Number` type. So I need to use a custom type (currently `BigNumber`) to represent those values.

I am looking hungrily at the proposed `BigInt` type, which when implemented as standard will be an improvement for many applications including the one I'm writing. However that won't help at all with JSON, which knows nothing about `BigInt` any more than `BigNumber`.

Whichever custom type I choose, there are many values of this type throughout the application state. So much that it's worth considering a custom hook in the serialisation / deserialisation layer that will handle transforming it to / from JSON.

Presumably the JSON document will have to represent the values as JSON native types (e.g. `Object` or `String` instances). How then, when de-serialising the entire complex application state, to reliably recognise and de-serialise those instances among all the others, to the correct value of the correct `BigInt` or `BigNumber` type?

How can I serialise that state, such that any `BigNumber` (or insert some other arbitrary-precision number type) value reliably survives the serialisation / de-serialisation process, to correct values of the correct type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If modifying the type (by adding a property to the prototype) is feasible, there is a [`toJSON` hook from `JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#toJSON()_behavior), designed specifically to help custom types collaborate with JSON serialisation.

> If an object being stringified has a property named `toJSON` whose value is a function, then the `toJSON()` method customizes JSON stringification behavior: instead of the object being serialized, the value returned by the `toJSON()` method when called will be serialized.

So you could add a new method to the `BigNumber` class:

```javascript
BigNumber.prototype.toJSON = function toJSON(key) {
    return {
        _type: 'BigNumber',
        _data: Object.assign({}, this),
    };
};

state = {
    lorem: true,
    ipsum: "Consecteur non dibale",
    dolor: new BigNumber(107.58),
    sit: { spam: 5, eggs: 6, beans: 7 },
    amet: false,
};
serialisedState = JSON.stringify(state);
console.debug("serialisedState:", serialisedState);
//  → '{"lorem":true,"ipsum":"Consecteur non dibale","dolor":{"_type":"BigNumber","_data":{"s":1,"e":2,"c":[1,0,7,5,8]}},"sit":{"spam":5,"eggs":6,"beans":7},"amet":false}'
```

You can then recognise those specific objects when de-serialising, using [the `reviver` parameter of `JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Using_the_reviver_parameter):

> If a `reviver` is specified, the value computed by parsing is *transformed* before being returned. Specifically, the computed value and all its properties (beginning with the most nested properties and proceeding to the original value itself) are individually run through the `reviver`. Then it is called, with the object containing the property being processed as `this`, and with the property name as a string, and the property value as arguments. [If the return value is not `undefined`], the property is redefined to be the return value.

```javascript
function reviveFromJSON(key, value) {
    let result = value;
    if (
        (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null)
            && (value.hasOwnProperty('_type'))) {
        switch (value._type) {
        case 'BigNumber':
            result = Object.assign(new BigNumber(0), value._data);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

state = JSON.parse(serialisedState, reviveFromJSON);
console.debug("state:", state);
// → { … dolor: BigNumber { s: 1, e: 2, c: [ 1, 0, 7, 5, 8 ] }, … }
```

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is [the Granola library for Node.js](https://github.com/kanongil/granola).

> granola provides a JSON compatible stringifier and parser with support for modern language and object primitives.

This would require:

- Convert the application from using `BigNumber` values to `BigInt` values.
- Wait for tools to support `BigInt` in the entire build tool chain.